# C++ Image Flow/Slider

Tags: c++, mfc, coverflow, imageflow

I have a software which displays small image thumbnails at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

But these sample 5 are just a small portion of all the available ones. I am looking for ideas of libraries or just available open source code that would let me animate them as they switch to the previous/next ones in the list when the arrow button is pressed or the user flicks them left/right like on an ipod.

I am NOT using Qt (as another answer suggests using it).

Comment: what platform do you use? what are your constraints on this app?

Comment: so maybe WPF (using C#) and embedd control in your native win32 window?

Answer (score 0):

Hey my be you need this one, has got nice animations and its native

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21006/Not-just-a-image-list-control-Neat-3D-iTunes-style